# Java Tries : Need a better approach

Tags: java, algorithm, trie

I am new to tries and testing how it works. Right now I am building a contact list. I add 'Prashanth' and 'Pradep' to the trie and when I search 'Pra' I should receive the count as two. My approach is having the variable *size* in each node and returning it when the string of same length is found. There are some unnecessary things/variables like payload etc which I used for debugging. The problem I found is when I store a character and a node in hashmap, empty node is getting stored. So I am getting 0 as answer all the time.

```
 public class tries {

public static class Node {

    HashMap<Character, Node> children = new HashMap<>();
    boolean endOfWord = false;
    int size =0;
    int payload = 10;


    public void setNode(char c, Node n) {
      children.put(c,n);
    }

    public Node getNode(char c) {
        return children.get(c);
    }

    public void addNode( String s,int index) {
        Node current = children.get(s.charAt(index));
        size++;
        if(index ==s.length()-1)
        {
            endOfWord = true;
            return;
        }
        if(current== null)

        {
             current.payload = 11;
            this.setNode(s.charAt(index),current);
        }
        addNode(s,index+1);

    }

    public int findcount(String s, int index) {
        Node current = children.get(s.charAt(index));

        if(index ==s.length()-1)
        {
            current.endOfWord = true;
            return current.size;
        }
        if(current == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }


        return findcount(s,index+1);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String c1 = "Prashanth";
    String c2=  "Pradep";
    Node n = new Node();
    //tries t = new tries();

    n.addNode(c1,0);
    n.addNode(c2,0);

    System.out.println(n.findcount("Pra",0));


}
```

}

> Error which I get If i run this code. ( I will get 0 if I alter a bit)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tries$Node.addNode(tries.java:35)
at tries.main(tries.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: So, do you get a NullPointerException or not? If yes, then post its stack trace; if no, change the title of your question.

Comment: problem is in `addNode` , line `this.setNode(s.charAt(index),current);` at first current will be *empty node* and you are setting that in `children` hash.

Comment: Are you trying to search for the contact? And is it ok to do it in another way?

Comment: @SunilBN : Right I get that. So I tried to initialize and add some data with payload. I am not getting it though

Comment: @triForce420 : Yes. This is just my beginning approach. You can always suggest

Comment: @JBNizet : Posted

Comment: @KrishnakanthJc check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class ContactList {

    Map<String, String> contactList; 

    public ContactList() {
        //initialize the map of contact lists. 
        contactList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void addContact(String name, String number){
        contactList.put(name, number);
    }

    public Map<String,String> findbyName(String name){

        Map<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(String key : contactList.keySet()){
            //trim and make the name lowercase, then compare it to the lowercased String
            if(key.trim().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())){
                resultMap.put(key, contactList.get(key));
            }
        }
        return resultMap;

    }

    public int countResult(String name){
        //return size of found map
        return findbyName(name).size();
    }



}
```

then use it on main method:

```
public class ContactMain {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String c1 = "Prashanth";
        String c2=  "Pradep";
        ContactList contacts = new ContactList();
        contacts.addContact(c1, "1234567890");
        contacts.addContact(c2, "12345678");
        System.out.println(contacts.countResult("Pra"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code works but I started this problem to learn tries. Can you help me with this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You check if the `current` is null and then if it is, you call something on it. See this block:

```
   if(current== null)
    {
         current.payload = 11;
        this.setNode(s.charAt(index),current);
    }
```

Notice the `current == null` and then `current.payload`. You can't call anything on `null`, it's a representation of nothing :)

What you probably want to do is create a new `Node`, initialize it, put it into the map and then assign it to `current`